# Serial Downvote Auto-corrector Bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, serial-voting

I had the pleasure of being on the receiving end of some serial downvoting yesterday. The daily auto-correcting script seems to have noticed and mostly corrected the mess. The downvotes are gone but the total scores for the questions and answers were not updated. For example, one of my questions had a score of 4 before the downvoting and 3 after, the score was still 3 after the serial downvoting was corrected but clicking on the total to see the up/down vote distribution reset the total to 4.

I fixed the cached scores for both questions and one of my answers while verifying the strange behavior. I'm pretty sure I could remember a couple more if the logs don't keep track of what the auto-correcting does.

I think my overall rep is fine but I also hit the cap yesterday so I wouldn't notice if it wasn't put back.

Is this a known problem (as minor as it is) or did I find a real bug?

---

Some examples: Answer 5574864 was showing as 26 before I checked the up/down spread and 27 after. I think answer 5741090 should be a 7 even though it shows as a 6; I can't check this one because checking would ruin my example (of course, someone will probably ruin it for me...). There should be seven of my answers where the vote totals don't add up; I "fixed" the scores for both of my questions and one of my answers while verifying that something was indeed wrong. All the affected answers were from May and June.

Comment: What do you mean by "I fixed the cached scores"? Also, example posts would be nice; hard to look at this without examples. The vote invalidation *should* correct the post scores.

Comment: @balpha: I added some examples (one fixed, one still (AFAIK) broken), hopefully you'll get to them before anyone else tries to verify the problem.

Comment: You can see the issue without side-effect by looking at [API request for the second answer](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/answers/5741090), which shows `"score": 6`, `"up_vote_count": 7`, and `"down_vote_count": 0`. Barring any lingering flags, it does seem like the values are out of sync.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks, looks like someone has "fixed" that one by checking the up/down vote numbers on SO. I saw your results earlier but now it is 7/7/0 as it should be. If I point out any others then well-meaning but curious people will probably mess things up again :)

Comment: Possibly related: [After a forced vote recalc, the old counts are still used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122263/after-a-forced-vote-recalc-the-old-counts-are-still-used)