# After a forced vote recalc, the old counts are still used

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, account-suspension, vote-count

> #### Summary: Vote counts have to be automatically corrected on a Vote count recalc.

I browsed through the [Top Users: JavaScript askers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) page, looking for nice questions. My attention was caught by a user at the bottom of the list, whose profile page showed:
[image: This user This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities.]

I opened some of his answers. Surprisingly, after clicking to retrieve the vote counts, the upvote count decreased. In some cases, the number of upvotes changed from 10 to 3!

Vote counts are an important indication of a post's quality; Wrong vote counts are just misleading...

### Methods and effects of viewing vote counts

- When vote counts are shown using the [1000 reputation **privilege**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user#footer-sites), the counters are **reset**.
- When vote counts are shown using **[this Userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699?view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)** (*not logged in*), the counters are **not reset**.

---

Once, someone started upvoting many of my answers. This was detected, and my vote counts were recalculated. I used the reputation audit to recalculate my reputation, and looked at the question for which I earned a badge. After clicking, the vote count changed from `+41 -1` to `+40 -1`. So, **the vote counts are not corrected when triggering a reputation recalc** either.

> #### Conclusion: When a vote recalc is triggered, all vote counts should be revised. Not just the up- and downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post scores are already synced up as part of a job that runs every night, so there's nothing more we will do here, it's so rare and expensive, it's absolutely not worth it to be real-time.

A reputation recalc **has no effect on the vote counts**...it can't change them, so it shouldn't recalc them - if it had any impact syncing them, it'd be pure coincidence, the number being out of sync was caused by something else.

What you saw was the result of someone undoing their vote or a user being deleted.