# Vote count not recalculated after serial-downvoting-reversal

Tags: bug, serial-voting, vote-count

Yesterday someone *serial-downvoted* some posts of mine. Later that was automatically reversed. I saw it in the rep tab of my profile.

But **the total vote-count is still wrong** if I open the question or view my question tab. I tried it in another browser where I don't use *Stack Overflow* and am not logged in.

If I click on the vote number it gets recalculated and is correct further on.

Example Questions I did **not** recalc yet:

[select-specific-elements-from-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013633/select-specific-elements-from-xml)
[sum-range-with-condition-in-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468897/sum-range-with-condition-in-excel)
and more...

**Update**

This bug report deals with a similar issue: [downvote negate 4 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184767/downvote-negate-4-reputation-points)

[image: Question Tab]

[image: Question]

[image: Question after recalc]

Comment: That's just the usually caching thing. Same thing happens when a user is removed.

Comment: And when does it get recalculated? The reversal was 13 hours ago.

Comment: Resolved already... Try clearing your cache. At least I see the correct vote count just now.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Only if someone clicks on the vote count of that question.

Comment: @juergend: No. I see the (cumulative) vote count being 0, instead of -1.

Comment: ***Please*** don't remove links to relevant content, it really makes bug reports infuriating to track down.  Link to the bug, *link to the bug*, **please link to the bug**.  It makes it far easier to fix more bugs if we don't spend 10x longer figuring out which post/user/page the last one was about.

Comment: @NickCraver: I removed the posts because they are recalculated now... Basically all reversed posts are incorrect, but now I don't think there are any not-recalculated left. :(

Comment: @juergend they have history we can see and Ids I can track down in scheduled task logs...me not having to go searching and typing in titles is time spent fixing the bug.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103847/serial-downvote-auto-corrector-bug ?

Answer (score 7):

I have *seen* this, but I am completely unable to repro it, nor should it be possible in our code.  What happens is this:

1. We do things that can throw the counts off,  mainly vote reversals (including some from community).
2. *Immediately* after, we sync up the the Score column on Posts that you see by totalling up the current votes and doing an UPDATE.  So it's by-design the counts get out of sync, but it *should* only be for a few seconds.

We are aware of the issue, I'm just scratching my head at the root cause.  It may be that on a large change job we're getting bitten by `READ UNCOMMITTED` and getting some dirty data in the `UPDATE` that trails.  I'll take another look tomorrow and see if anything else comes to mind.

*Edit:* there is a deadlock case we specifically exclude from logs on scheduled tasks - I added some logging specifically for this method to see if that's happening here.  I haven't gotten a notification from our SQL monitors so I doubt it...but maybe.  If that's the case, I have to go see why the SQL server monitoring didn't pick it up...and I have 2 problems.

Comment: I just had a similar issue on that post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860592/575376. It is deleted and showed a vote total of 0. But after clicking on the count to see the up/downvote split, it changed to -1 without showing the split. Another click showed the split with +1/-2.

Answer (score 3):

I have witnessed this when deleting sock puppets. I am a little CDO (OCD in alphabetical order), and often go through their recent posts and expand the votes to 'fix' the display.

I once waited two days to do so, and it still only updated when I expanded.

This is not a big deal when it's just a single vote, but I've seen multi-socks causing weak/bad answers to appear highly rated, which is why I try to fix them manually.