# downvote negate 4 reputation points

Tags: discussion, support, status-norepro, reputation, serial-voting

Being a victim of serial-downvoting today I found an odd behavior for [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press)

two days before when someone downvoted the post it show as:

> [image: two days ago]

and today again it shows:

> [image: today]

voting counts show me as:

> [image: voting counts]

I am surprised why it is subtracting 4 points on this particular post, for all other posts in serial-downvoting -2 reputation was considered. Is there any specific post or scenario where -4 is considered, or its just a bug?

Comment: Two events = Two Downvotes. I see a triangle that expands and shows that on the -4 row. But the triangle doesn't appear in your screenshot.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Should be -2 instead of -4 since you have only 1 downvote left on that post.

Comment: its not showing two events and on downvoting reversed it reverted 4 points which shows it was the same user otherwise it wont reverted.

Comment: There should be a disclosure arrow to the left of the post which when clicked on shows that you received two separate downvotes on that same post. There is no bug here.

Comment: @juergend I see two downvotes on that post.

Comment: @Servy: I see only 1.

Comment: @juergend One vote was reversed.  If you look on the OP's profile, on the reputation tab, it shows two downvotes.  If you look on the post itself, it only has one.  There is also an entry for serial voting reversal, of which it clearly reversed one of the votes on that post.

Comment: Ah. Looks like that disclosure arrow only appears if you have "post" selected rather than "time"

Comment: @Servy: If I sort the rep tab by post and not by time I can finally see what you see.

Comment: @Oded: Did you mean to put a red status tag on this, or create a new tag [status]? /cleanup

Comment: @animuson - thanks. It was supposed to be a no-repro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the reputation tab of your profile I see this:

[image: reputation history]

There were two downvotes on that post, one 1 hour ago and one 4 hours ago.  One of the votes was reversed from the "serial downvoting reversed" entry that you can see from an hour ago.

If you're looking at the rep history through the "time" view, and not the "post" view, then you won't be able to see the breakdown of how many events contributed to the reputation change, just the net reputation change.  (This applies to upvotes as well as downvotes.)

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: Sort your rep tab by post and not by time.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed As I said; one of the downvotes was reversed, which is why the post only has one downvote now.