# Issue with non-updating votes on serial downvote reversal

Tags: bug, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

Recently I was serial down-voted by a unhappy fellow SO user when I marked their question as off-topic. Naturally, I waited for 24-hours and the serial down-vote was indeed reversed. However, I noticed that my vote counts for all my questions **did not update** (See *Fig A*). Curious, I clicked into each question and clicked on the vote counts and, like magic, when the vote breakdown appeared, the vote was "updated" to the pre-downvoted state. Refreshing my user profile on SO also shows the updated vote count **for that question only**.

I recognized that the "outdated" vote count plagues all the votes that were reversed and that refreshing the page, logging out and in again both did not solve the issue.

*Fig A.*

[image: Voting overview in User Profile]

The highlighted red box will not show updated votes for every question/answer that had its voting reversed.

*Fig B.*

[image: Question with outdated vote]

The actual Q&A page will also show outdated votes until I press `View upvote and downvote totals` in which the "updated" vote is displayed and updated everywhere else (Both *Fig A* and *Fig B*).

Unless I'm missing some great detail here, can someone explain to me why this is? (And also, can anyone else confirm this behavior?)

Comment: Caching, its always caching

Comment: @RichardTingle On my end (i.e my computer) or the server's end?

Comment: Server end, a **lot** of things on stack exchange are heavily cached to enable it to sustain the load its under

Comment: @RichardTingle Sorry if it sounds stupid but, is there any "solution" to this? Afterall, I did come on SO 5 ~ 6 hours after the vote reversal was made... Do they really cache data for _that_ long?

Comment: @CPUTerminator Definitely. Things like these **may** be cached for days. Or cached until updated.. ie, someone checks-vote-count/upvotes/downvotes it, forcing it to update.

Comment: We'd need a dev to answer authoratitively (one will probably be along shortly) but yes. The solution is basically to wait for the caches to update

Comment: @RichardTingle Oh what fun... I already manually "Check vote counts" everything that was down-voted, can't stand those -1s. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: [This question is related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184315/vote-count-not-recalculated-after-serial-downvoting-reversal). It seems like the same issue. I have seen these invalidated votes go for quite some time without ever being updated, until I clicked to expand the votes.